# Get local User group members - Powershell

Tags: powershell, security-groups

```
$Output = 'C:\temp\Result.txt'
$Servers = Get-Content 'C:\temp\ServerNames.txt'
$ScriptBlock = {

$Groups = Get-WmiObject Win32_GroupUser -ComputerName $Servers 
$LocalAdmins = $Groups | Where GroupComponent –like '*"Administrators"'

$LocalAdmins |% {  
$_.partcomponent –match ".+Domain\=(.+)\,Name\=(.+)$" > $nul  
$matches[1].trim('"') + "\" + $matches[2].trim('"')
}
}
foreach ($ServerNames in $Servers) {
"Local Admin group members in $ServerNames" | Out-File $Output -Append
Invoke-command -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ComputerName $ServerNames | Out-  File $Output -Append
}
```

I am using the above mentioned script to get local admins group members to run against multiple servers, I am getting error -

> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the 
>   command again.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
>       + PSComputerName        : Computer

Can you pls assist me to correct that...?

Server Names in the file ServerNames.txt are in this format mentioned below -

[ServerNames.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4WGt.jpg)

Comment: Do you have a file named ServerNames.txt located in C:\temp with a list of server names in the file?

Comment: Yes,I do have that file name in C:\temp with server names

Comment: Would you mind posting the contents of the file?

Comment: Applbtrn01
Applbtrn02
Applbtrn03
Applbtrn04
Applbtrn05
Applbtrn06
Applbtrn07

Comment: Its one below the other...I was trying that same format here, for some reasons its not letting me

Comment: Would you please update the question and make sure the formatting is the same as the file?

Comment: attached the screenshot for those server names...FYI

Comment: shouldn't the match line in the scriptblock be inside an if command? Thr following line will be executed even if there was no match.

Comment: Hi LotPings...can you pls explain how I can change that...I am still in the learning process...

Comment: If you want me to get a notification prepend the username with an `@`. See my answer.

Comment: If you open this PowerShell script in PowerShell ISE, run the script, run `echo $Servers`, then what do you get?

Comment: I am getting the server names in the ServerNames.txt file...

Comment: its working fine when using script edited by LotPings......Another thing is because its windows server 2008 R2...I am getting this message mentioned below - Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : The client cannot connect to th e destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests . Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or Win RM. run the command and configure WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Output = 'C:\temp\Result.txt'
$Servers= Get-Content 'C:\temp\ServerNames.txt'
$ScriptBlock = {
    $Groups = Get-WmiObject Win32_GroupUser -ComputerName $Using:ServerName
    $LocalAdmins = $Groups | Where GroupComponent –like '*"Administrators"'
    $LocalAdmins | ForEach-Object {  
        If($_.partcomponent –match ".+Domain\=(.+)\,Name\=(.+)$"){  
            $matches[1].trim('"') + "\" + $matches[2].trim('"')
        }
    }
}
ForEach ($ServerName in $Servers) {
    "Local Admin group members in $ServerName" | Out-File $Output -Append
    Invoke-command -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ComputerName $ServerName | Out-File $Output -Append
}
```

But IMO this could be a bit simplified without the unnecessary vars

```
$Output = 'C:\temp\Result.txt'
$Servers= Get-Content 'C:\temp\ServerNames.txt'
$ScriptBlock = {
    Get-WmiObject Win32_GroupUser -ComputerName $Using:ServerName |
    Where GroupComponent –like '*"Administrators"'|
    ForEach-Object {  
        If($_.partcomponent –match ".+Domain\=(.+)\,Name\=(.+)$"){  
            $matches[1].trim('"') + "\" + $matches[2].trim('"')
        }
    }
}
ForEach ($ServerName in $Servers) {
    "Local Admin group members in $ServerName" | Out-File $Output -Append
    Invoke-command -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ComputerName $ServerName | Out-File $Output -Append
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error - 

Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again. + CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ParameterBindingValidationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand + PSComputerName : Applbtrn07

Comment: I changed the var inside the scriptblock to $Using:... to get actual values invoking. [See this blog](http://www.padisetty.com/2014/05/all-about-powershell-scriptblock.html)

Comment: @LotPings...its working fine. my apologies there were some typos in the script.Another thing is because its windows server 2008 R2...I am getting this message mentioned below - 

Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : The client cannot connect to th
e destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests
. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or Win
RM. run the command and configure 
WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig".

Comment: So the question is answered and you should check my asnwer. For the new problem investigate and eventually post another question. Good luck with this.